# Is it possible to renew an Apple Enterprise License prior to deadline

Tags: license

As we come to year end, I wanted to get handle on our licensing.  Although I have until April 2020, it got me thinking, is it possible to renew a license prior to the auto-renew date? See screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can renew at most 30 days before expiry.

> Alternatively, you can renew manually starting 30 days before the expiration date of your existing membership or any time after it expires.

https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/

This does not lose any days of the membership though, since renewing ‘early’ does not take effect until the previous membership expires.